# Cannot find "page-chooser-modal.js" when trying to add new site after upgrade v2.5

Tags: wagtail

I have a demo site which I'm trying to get live (just learning...). When I try to add a new site in the CMS admin (under settings-->sites-->"add site") and try to choose a root page through the selection modal, It won't allow a page to be selected. My relevant pages appear (those under 'root'), but can't be selected.

If I try to click through to see the children of these pages, I get the following error in the log:
Not Found: /static/wagtailadmin/js/page-chooser-modal.js

All this is after I dropped my database and installed wagtail v2.5 fresh (since upgraded to v2.5.1). This issue doesn't occur with v2.0 on my localhost.

Python is V 3.6.6
Django is V 2.0.9

Comment: Hi Lewis. If you upgraded from a different version, try giving the page a hard refresh. More often than not the browser will cache old files to make pages load faster.

Comment: Is this happening on a production server (as opposed to running locally with `manage.py runserver`)? If so, have you re-run `manage.py collectstatic` after upgrading?

Comment: Yes this is on a production server and running collectstatic worked! Thanks!